# Extracting seconds from a pandas TimeStamp series: 'Series' object has no attribute 'second'

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a CSV file using pandas, where one of the columns has a TimeStamp value that looks like this:
`2022.7.11/11:34:36:372`
My end goal is to extract the TimeStamp value as datetime and subsequently get the values of seconds that I want to use in further arithmetic operations.

So far the code I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv(location, encoding='utf8', delimiter=';')
s = pd.Series((df['TimeStamp']).values).str.split('/', n=4 ,expand=True)
t1 = pd.to_datetime(s[1] , format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

But when I try to get the seconds value from t1, using t1.second I get an exception that says: > 'Series' object has no attribute 'second'

Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: doesn't work, it says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: did you typecast it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typecasting the object to datetime column , you should be able to access seconds using :

```
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%Y.%m.%d/%H:%M:%S:%f')
df['TimeStamp'].dt.second

0    36
Name: TimeStamp, dtype: int64
```

You can access the microsecond part using

```
df['TimeStamp'].dt.microsecond
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `t1.dt.second` instead of `t1.second`